# How to clean data in dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-extraction

Hi need help for cleansing a data from a excel file using python. below is the sample table.

As you can see column "Account Name" as some string values from column "Billing Street"

[image: Input file]

I need to replace all the matching string (from "Billing Street") to blank in column "Account Name", if there is no string matching just need to retain the same value from "Account Name".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

File= pd.read_excel('Test_data_for_script.xlsx')
File1=File.copy()

File_1['CLEANSE_NAME']= File_1['Account Name'].str.strip(File_1['Billing Street'])
```

using the above method the output was "NaN".

Below is the expected result.

[image: Output required]

Comment: pls add input and ouput as a text. avoid adding images

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

*Based on your comment - There are approaches that could handle specific cases, but this requires knowledge of potential patterns.*

One approach could therefore be to extend the previous one and look for differences or partial similarities and use these for the replacement.

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def longestSubstring(row):
    str1 = row.A
    str2 = row.B
    seqMatch = SequenceMatcher(None,str1,str2)
    match = seqMatch.find_longest_match(0, len(str1), 0, len(str2))

    if (match.size>1):
        return str1.replace(str1[match.a: match.a + match.size],'')
    else:
        return str1

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':['A - some B text','A - some other B text', 'A - just A','A - some other B text'], 
        'B':['B text','other B text','no matching','something and other B text']
     })
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: longestSubstring(row), axis=1)
df
```

##### Output

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A - some B text | B text | A - some |
| 1 | A - some other B text | other B text | A - some |
| 2 | A - just A | no matching | A - just A |
| 3 | A - some other B text | something and other B text | A - some |

---

You could `apply()` a `replace()` to each row of dataframe.

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':['A - some B text','A - some other B text', 'A - just A'], 
        'B':['B text','other B text','no matching']
     })
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.A.replace(row.B,''), axis=1)
df
```

##### Output

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A - some B text | B text | A - some |
| 1 | A - some other B text | other B text | A - some |
| 2 | A - just A | no matching | A - just A |

Comment: This helped, but for the 3rd row from my question i need to remove the partial match from other cell which is in a sequence.


Account Name- Trane Chicago "7100 Madison"
Billing street    -"7100 Madison"  ATTN JOHN REICHARDT

Required output -Trane Chicago

Comment: edited my answer and added an alternative, that could cover this specific behavior. solution could only point in a direction, to cover all possible behavior you have to adapt and extend it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use apply and replace function from pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

File = pd.read_excel("Test_data_for_script.xlsx")
File1 = File.copy()

File1["CLEANSE_NAME"] = File1.apply(
    lambda row: row["Account Name"].replace(row["Billing Street"], ""), axis=1
)

print(File1)
```